# Rails update_attribute does not work on production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

Logs on production:

```
irb(main):036:0> People.find(7).update_attribute(:all_read,[2,3])
  People Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
  People Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
   (0.7ms)  COMMIT
   (0.7ms)  COMMIT
  People Store (29.1ms)  {"id":7}
  People Store (29.1ms)  {"id":7}
=> true
irb(main):037:0> People.find(7).all_read
  People Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
  People Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
=> []
```

This works perfectly locally but it doesn't work on heroku.
I am using sqlite3 locally, postgresql on heroku.

Other related code:

```
class People < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :all_read, Array

schema.db
  create_table "people", force: :cascade do |t|
    ...
    t.string   "all_read",            default: "--- []\n"
  end
```

Comment: What's on the production logs?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your version of your DB.
Also check version of gem in group development and production.

I did not see the update query in your log.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite and postgres are very different
use same database while developing

for example varchar in postgres is specified length string and in sqlite is unlimited.

if you want to find what is the exact problem, after your update_attribute call 
the .errors method (with byebug or logger) to see the problem